# How to count in LEFT JOIN table

Tags: mariadb, where-clause, left-join, sql-null

```
SELECT emp.`emp_id`,cio.`pin`,cio.`checktime` FROM payroll.employees AS emp 

    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM zkteco_biotime.checkinout WHERE checktime > "2022-09-20 23:59:59") AS cio ON emp.emp_id = cio.pin

    WHERE emp.status=0 GROUP BY emp_id ORDER BY checktime DESC
```

I want to retrieve only `NULL` values in the checktime or pin columns. However, when I use `AND cio.checktime=NULL` after `emp.status=0` it shows me a blank result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
AND cio.checktime IS NULL
```

Null compared with anything will result in FALSE. Only "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" may return TRUE.

Comment: Null-safe compare can be used too - `AND cio.checktime <=> NULL`

Comment: Maybe, but seams like 2 more chars and much more complex to understand, no?